# Word problem fractions

Tags: word-problem

A recipe calls for $3$ cans of condensed milk. Each can holds $\frac{1}{2}$ cups of condensed milk. If Alice wants to cut recipe in half, how much condensed milk will she need?

answer:
$$
\frac31 \times \frac12 \times \frac12
$$

I did not understand the answer,if she want to cut the recipe in half ,why is not divided by 1/2 instead of multiplied by $\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: Dividing by $1/2$ is the same as multiplying by $2$. Can you see why that would be wrong?

Comment: Note that the answer needs the word "cups" at the end to make it clear that is what the number is (One could just as easily ask how many cans would she need, which would be a different answer)

Comment: What you mean by :”Can you see why  that would be wrong”?

Answer (score 1):

"Cutting in half" means "dividing by $2$", which is the same as "multiplying by $\frac12$".

Answer (score 0):

The recipe calls for 3 cans, each holds $\frac12$ of a cup. So total recipe content is $3 \times \frac12 = \frac32$ of a cup.

You need another $\frac12$ of that since Alice is halving the recipe...